# How to toggle checked state using android accessibility service?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility

I am not able to toggle the checked state of ui node with class `android.widget.Switch` I have tried `.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SELECT)` and `.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK)` but it didn't workout. Thanks for the help..

Comment: You want to make the switch on or off, whether accessibility service is enabled or not? Is that the question?

Comment: I just want to make the switch on or off using my own accessibility service.

Answer (score 0):

You may set the state of the `Switch` as checked through its `View` object when some event occours (like a button click):

```
ViewCompat.setAccessibilityLiveRegion(mySwitch, ViewCompat.ACCESSIBILITY_LIVE_REGION_POLITE)
mySwitch.isChecked = true
```

Setting the accessibility state as checked would be possible using `AccessibilityDelegate`, but for a `Switch`, the current `View` state (on or off) is more important than the one set from the delegate. Below is the code to set a custom `AccessibilityDelegate` to a `View`.

```
ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(mySwitch, object : AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {
    override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host: View?, info: AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat?) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)

        info?.isChecked = true
    }
})
```